# SVG node.getBBox incorrect when using @font-face

Tags: javascript, css, svg, fonts, raphael

I have some text that gets rendered using `Raphael.text()` and with `font-family` attributes that use fonts loaded using @font-face.

I use OpenType to load the font and render it as base64 and inject that in my stylesheet.

Here's some pseudo code:

```
// In my css
opentype.load('someFontFamily', (err, font) => {
  // Inject in stylesheets
  const path = paper.text(x, y, 'Hello World')
    .attr({
      'font-family': 'someFontFamily'
      'font-size': 100
    })
  path.getBBox() // Calls path.node.getBBox() in RaphaelJS
})
```

The issue is this. The size, especially the width,as retured by getBBox is not reflective of the font family but instead of some abstract unknown generic font (it's not quite the width of the fallback font so not sure what it is).

The html/page is correctly showing my SVG with the desired font. I can inspect it and the browser sees the correct size.

It's not a question of waiting, I've tried timeouts. It seems that the only way it will work if is the font is preloaded in browser (by having an element on the page using the family and using `@font-face` in my css which causes a triggering of the font download prior to any SVG rendering.

I've tried adding my fonts as `@font-face` declarations prior to page loading but it makes no diff.

How can I get SvG to return the size reflecting the font it displays? I suspect it's an internal timing question. It's almost like a need a callback/event for the post render.

Answer (score 3):

Ok. Posting an answer in case it proves useful to some other poor soul.

There are indeed some implementations of the @font-face loading events.

Here's a good [article](https://dev.opera.com/articles/better-font-face/) on this.

Cross browser support is still iffy but Font Face Observer looks like a promising library:

- https://github.com/bramstein/fontfaceobserver

Also of interest is:

- https://github.com/zachleat/fontfaceonload

Some browsers natively support these events. After rendering my text I can call:

```
document.fonts.load('70px someFontFamily')
  .then(function() {
    console.log(path.node.getBBox())
  })
```